# For a given shape, find set of points with the maximum average distance

Tags: packing

Within some shape, I want to find a set of points where the distance between each point is maximized. This seems similar to sphere packing to me except that part of the sphere can be outside the shape.

Comment: What is this shape? Is it fixed? What is your input? Is it 2D?

Comment: polytope of any dimensions but mostly interested in the 2D or 3D case

Comment: The *set* of points with maximum average distance will always be a *pair* of points of maximum distance.  (E.g. in a circle, two points at either end of a diameter line segment.)  If that's not the answer you wanted/expected, please refine your question.